# Is there a way in RAML 0.8 to show the data structure of the example?

Tags: raml

I am creating a RAML for one of my projects and I have a case where one of the APIs has a query param which is of DTO type. So, how do I write the example and "Type" of that query param?

```
QueryParam:
    description: Some description.
    type: DTO
    required: true
    example: ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters can only be of [primitive type](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#type)

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: GitHub API
version: v3
baseUri: https://api.github.com/{version}
/users:
  get:
    description: Get a list of users
    queryParameters:
      page:
        description: Specify the page that you want to retrieve
        type: integer
        required: true
        example: 1
```

Requests/responses body can use json, in that case the type is a [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) and the example a json:

```
/jobs:
  displayName: Jobs
  post:
    description: Create a Job
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: |
          {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
            "properties": {
                "input": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": false,
            "type": "object"
          }
        example: { "input": "foo" }
```